# How to get items out of a list in CSV

Tags: python, list, csv

So I have this csv file about artists, with every artist having matching genres. For each artist, I used Python to get recommended artists and the genres associated to those.

What I ultimately want is to compare the average popularity of the genres for the artists and the average popularity of the genres of the recommended artists. The original artists' genres were already in the list (see: Line 4). The way the recommended artists' genres were scraped put them in a list after which they were written into a csv (see: Line 8).

Now the problem is that the way I calculated the means for the artists' genres won't work for the recommended artists' genres, probably because those genres are in the csv as lists.

Is there a way to remove the brackets for each list in the csv and to have them appear in the same way (not as a list/no brackets) as the artists' genres (Line 4) so I can calculate the average popularity of them too?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello @Lau could you please share the efforts you made in order to solve this problem accompanied by the relevant snapshots/text of csv file and desired output ?

Comment: Hi Tanishq, I forgot to include the screenshot, apologies! https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTBeS.png

Comment: you need to provide code not screenshots, see [ask] a question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Lau could you share your python code as well. Also the image that you have shared is a bit unclear as to what you want. Could you make an edit that has a basic example of the main problem using some fake data. It would be much easier for everyone to understand and help you at the earliest.

Comment: Sure, no problem! Is there a way to share this in a private message?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `writerows` function of the csvwriter class to do this all at once without a loop.

```
with open("testFile.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerows(listOfRows)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Revisto, thank you for your answer. When doing this, won't this affect my whole csv? It's only one specific column that needs the contents to be extracted from the list and put back in without the brackets, like the genres in line 4. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTBeS.png)